# Mongodb $ne date query not working as expected

Tags: mongodb

I have collection with Below data. While I am using `db.collection.find({endDate: {$ne:  new Date()}})` it's also showing result of current date which is *"05 JULY 2018"*.

```
{ 
    "_id" : "GMDJcQMfs8j8EP9EE", 
    "endDate" : ISODate("2018-07-05T14:59:08.794+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "GMDJcQMfs12233", 
    "endDate" : ISODate("2020-02-21T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "GMDJerrr8j8EP9EE", 
    "endDate" : ISODate("2020-02-21T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "rrrJcQMfs8j8EP9EE", 
    "endDate" : ISODate("2020-02-21T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

[Plese see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDG5L.png)

Comment: You either need to use `$lte` and `$gte` or some aggregation query to match the exact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by transforming your date to string, adding current date with same format, comare both and filter identical results :

```
db.test1.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                endDate:1,
                endDateFormatted:{$dateToString: {date:"$endDate",format:"%Y-%m-%d"}},
                current:{$dateToString: {date:new Date(),format:"%Y-%m-%d"}}
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {  ab: {$cmp: ['$endDateFormatted','$current']},endDate:1}
        },
        {
            $match: {ab:{$ne:0}}
        },
        {
        $project: {
           endDate:1
        }
    },
    ]
);
```

Output:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "GMDJcQMfs12233", 
    "endDate" : ISODate("2020-02-21T01:00:00.000+0100")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "GMDJerrr8j8EP9EE", 
    "endDate" : ISODate("2020-02-21T01:00:00.000+0100")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "rrrJcQMfs8j8EP9EE", 
    "endDate" : ISODate("2020-02-21T01:00:00.000+0100")
}
```