# Mongodb $gte date query not working as expected

Tags: mongodb

I have collection with Below data. While I am using

```
db.collection.find({ endDate: { $gte: new Date() } })
```

it's not showing result of current date which is `ISODate("2018-07-06T14:59:08.794+0000")`.

```
{ 
    "_id" : "GMDJcQMfs8j8EP9EE", 
    "endDate" : ISODate("2018-07-06T14:59:08.794+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "GMDJcQMfs12233", 
    "endDate" : ISODate("2020-02-21T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "GMDJerrr8j8EP9EE", 
    "endDate" : ISODate("2020-02-21T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "rrrJcQMfs8j8EP9EE", 
    "endDate" : ISODate("2020-02-21T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

Comment: "of current date which is "05 JULY 2018"" - there is also the time part. If I were to guess, your `new Date()` gave you a timestamps that is greater than that timestamp from jul 5th. But it's impossible to tell, because you didn't include enough info in the question. Post a reproducible and complete piece of code, without using parameterless `new Date()`, but rather `new Date(2018, 7, 5, ...)` (so that we all get the same result on any of our machines, any day of the year)

Comment: new Date(2018, 7, 5, ...) not working

Comment: Of course. Because you were supposed to expand the ellipsis.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev  , I have updated the question

Comment: yep, much better. If you now run the code from the question, you'll see that the query does return the today's document.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/44GwFh2r

Comment: @SergioTulentsev 
- Still not working
- I don't have account of  pastebin.com/

Comment: You don't _need_ an account there.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - this helped me var date = new Date()
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
db.collection.find({ endDate: { $gte: date } })

Comment: Ah yes, my original hypothesis was true, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider the time of the day. You can set the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds of the requested date back to zero.

```
var date = new Date()
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
db.collection.find({ endDate: { $gte: date } })
```

Now all records ending today and later will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you have quoted is $gte and the date you are passing for to the condition is newDate().

```
print(new Date()) - Execute this command in Mongo shell it Should be giving you the current date

My Console output

Fri Jul 06 2018 14:28:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

If your date is also Jul 06, 2018 then you also wont get the Jul 05, 2018 in your results

Comment: It was Fri Jul 05 2018 14:33:14 GMT+0530 (IST)

Comment: yesterday it was  Fri Jul 05 2018 14:33:14 GMT+0530 (IST) NOT JULY 06

Comment: That is not quite correct. The time of the day is considered, too.

Comment: @mbuechmann - Yes exactly, always time stamp is taken into account, so for that,  I have asked to check and compare the current shell date with the date available in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i get back on [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51198318/2276898) and explain it :

```
db.test1.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                endDate:1,
                endDateFormatted:{$dateToString: {date:"$endDate",format:"%Y-%m-%d"}},
                current:{$dateToString: {date:new Date(),format:"%Y-%m-%d"}}
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {  ab: {$cmp: ['$endDateFormatted','$current']},endDate:1}
        },
        {
            $match: {ab:{$eq:1}}  // <= note de difference with your previous question
        },
        {
        $project: {
           endDate:1
        }
    },
    ]
);
```

### Explanations :

- $dateToString transforms provided ISOdate in provided format, ie

> {$dateToString: {date:ISODate("2020-02-21T00:00:00.000+0000"),format:"%Y-%m-%d"}}  outputs "2020-02-01"

- $cmp compare first value A with second B, with following result :

  - A -1
  - A=B  => 0
  - A>B  => 1

just adapt ab criteria to what you need ({$eq:1} for future dates, {$eq:-1} for past dates, {$eq:0} for current date, {$ne:0} for not today dates, etc...  )

Comment: This is quite inefficient, as `dateToString` has to be executed on every document of the collection. This does not scale well, as you cannot create an index to boost performance.